# error C2039: 'normType' : is not a member of 'cv::DMatch'

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, match, sift

I try to do SIFT algorithm with c++, opencv 2.4.5. my project must do those:4 books figures are tracked in a video by sift. I found this code http://fahmifahim.com/2012/12/11/opencv-sift-implementation-in-opencv-2-4/

first of all I try to simple matching two figure. Later, i will implement other processes of project.
I change the code a litte at the up link. my code :

```
cv::Mat feat1, feat2; 
cv::Mat tmp = cv::imread( "c:\\image1.png", 1 );
cv::Mat in = cv::imread( "c:\\image1.png", 1 );


cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor detector(0.05,5);
cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor( 3);

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>  keypoints1, keypoints2 ;
detector.detect(tmp, keypoints1);
detector.detect( in, keypoints2 );

cv::drawKeypoints(tmp, keypoints1, feat1, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
cv::drawKeypoints(in , keypoints2, feat2, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
cv::imwrite( "feat1.bmp", feat1 );
cv::imwrite( "feat2.bmp", feat2 );
int key1 = keypoints1.size();
int key2 = keypoints2.size();
printf("Keypoint1=%d \nKeypoint2=%d", key1, key2);

cv::Mat descriptor1,descriptor2;
extractor.compute( tmp, keypoints1, descriptor1 );
extractor.compute( in, keypoints2, descriptor2 );
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
cv::BruteForceMatcher < cv::DMatch> matcher;
matcher.match(descriptor1,descriptor2, matches);

// matching result
cv::Mat result;
cv::drawMatches(tmp, keypoints1, in, keypoints2, matches, result);


// output file
cv::imwrite( "result.bmp", result );

// display the result
cvNamedWindow("SIFT", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow("SIFT", result);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

ı get error lik this: error C2039: 'normType' : is not a member of 'cv::DMatch'

what is wrong?

Comment: Can you mark which line of code gives the error?

Comment: BruteForceMatcher<L2 > matcher;

Comment: these lines give error                                                            std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
cv::BruteForceMatcher < cv::DMatch> matcher;
matcher.match(descriptor1,descriptor2, matches);